# Number of bits Per Column in DRAM

Tags: dram

In DDR3, DDR4 DRAM ,I don't get the point that each column gives more than one bits?? Column decoder is also a mux which selects one of the bits in row buffer, and DRAM array is a crossed structure with each column is essentially a bit line. How could there be 4 or 8 bits per column??

Comment: If you are talking about DDR3,DDR4 etc.. Modern CPU's use 64bit-bus because they use a 64-bit architecture so they will likely need the extra bytes.In DDR especially there are doubled  bits/bytes per transfer because of the Double Data Rate

Comment: Also the bus gets wider if you run Dual channel/ Quad /etc. RAM configurations. This Achieves greater bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. I new about the DDR thing and bus width, rank , bank etc.. But multiple bits per column is where I am stuck!!

Comment: You mean you you get more than one value with one set of coordinates?

Comment: Yes exactly this is what the literature says. When you give a column address to coulmn decoder you get a byte or half byte.

Comment: You will have 64-cells in this case with the same coordinates

Comment: @StavrosAvramidis Does current CPUs still use 64 bit bus? What/which bus anyway?

Comment: this might help understanding:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xtWsQvOcjo

Answer (score 2):

Each "logical" column is actually implemented using multiple physical columns on the chip. When you ask for a burst transfer, the physical memory array inside the chip performs a single cycle, transferring, say, 64 bits all at once. Those bits will be serialized as 8 bytes over the external 8-bit bus in a DDR burst using 4 clock cycles.

Does this help?

Comment: Thanks for your help. @Dave  Tweed can you suggest me to some material that explain it in a little more detail with some figures??

Comment: Not really. My knowledge is mostly inferred from studying the chip datasheets (reading between the lines in some cases) and building memory controllers in FPGAs.